# ¿Txtfield no dejan escribir?

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo un problema con mi form en netbeans, de un momento no me volvió a dejar escribir en los textfield cuando lo ejecuto.
creo otro jframe y normal si deja pero este que tengo no, y no se porque, alguien que le haya pasado y tenga alguna idea de como solucionarlo les agradecería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si tiene la opción editable activada, este es una parte del codigo pero ósea lo demás no creo que tenga que ver porque es la accion de imprimir y eso,
ósea porque es en si no pudo escribir en los textfield como si estuvieran bloqueados.

este es el codigo

```
public class frmPersonas extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Printable {

DefaultTableModel model;

/**
 * Creates new form frmPersonas
 */
public frmPersonas() {
    initComponents();
    
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmPersonas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmPersonas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmPersonas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmPersonas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
    this.limpiar();
    TxtFecha.setText(FechaActual());
    String[] titulos = {"ID", "Fecha", "Ciudad", "Programa", "JorDiurna", "JorNocturna", "PrimerApell", "SegundoApell", "Nombres", "FechaNaci", "LugarNaci", "Eps", "Ars", "CualAseguradora", "NivelSisben", "OtroSisben", "CC", "TI", "Otro", "NumeroDoc", "Expedida", "Masculino", "Femenino", "Edad", "TipoSangre", "Soltero", "Casado", "UnionL", "EstadoOtro", "Ocupacion", "Correo", "DireccionReside", "Telefono", "Barrio", "Estrato", "EntidadTraba", "Cargo", "FechaIngreso", "DireccionEmpre", "TelefonoEmpre", "NombreAcu", "CedulaAcu", "FechaNaciAcudi", "TelefonoAcu", "Parentesco", "ProfesionAcud", "SecundariaInsti", "SecundariaCiudad", "SecundariaTitu", "SecundariaAño", "TecnicoInstitu", "TecnicoCiudad", "TecnicoTitulo", "TecnicoAño", "UniveInstitu", "UniveCiudad", "UniveTitu", "UniveAño", "CulturaIndige", "CulturaAfro", "CulturaReinsi", "CulturaRoom", "CulturaCabezaF", "CulturaFronte", "CulturaDezpla", "PagoCredito", "PagoContado"};
    model = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
    tblInscritos.setModel(model);
    mostrarDatos();
    
}
// AGREGAR NUEVO INSCRITO

private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    conexion objConexion = new conexion();
    /*objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL("INSERT INTO inscritos (ID,fecha,ciudad,programa,JorDiurna,JorNocturna,primerApell,segundoApell,nombres,fechaNaci,lugarNacimi,eps,ars,cualAseguradora,nivelSisben,otroSisben,docuCC,docuTi,docuOtro,NumDocume,Expedida,generoM,generoF,edad,tipoSangre,estadoCivilSoltero,estadoCivilCasada,estadoCivilUnionL,estadoCivilOtro,ocupacion,correoElec,direccionReside,telefono,barrio,estrato,entidadTrabaja,cargo,fechaIngresoEm,direccionEmpre,telefonoEmpre,nombreAcudiente,cedulaAcudiente,fechaNaciAcudiente,telefonoAcudiente,parentesco,profesionAcudiente,secundariaInstitu,secundariaCiudad,secundariaTitulo,secundariaAno,tecnicoInstitucion,tecnicoCiudad,tecnicoTitulo,tecnicoAno,univeInstitucion,univeCiudad,univeTitulo,univeAno,culturaIndigena,culturaAfro,culturaReinser,culturaRoom,culturaCabezaF,culturaFrontera,culturaDezpla,pagoCredito,pagoContado) VALUES (null,'22/22/1111','bucaramanga','psicologia','x','x','almeida','moreno','jaime alberto','12/22/1222','florida','x','x','sura','5','x','si','x','x','1095787694','22/112/221',\n" +
        "'x','x','20','o+','x','no','no','no','si','almeidamorneojai@gail.com','piedecuesta','109232343','nn','5','efor','programador','21/02/200','27.23','123445','efrain','54645','34/34/34','3454354','padre','nn','x','q','w','j','k','d','d','f','s','g','g','d','nn','aa','sd','ff','gg','we','tr','gt','d')");
     */ personasBL oPersonas = recuperarDatosGui();
    if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena1)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        AuxiliarEnfermeria++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena2)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        AuxiliarSaludOral++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena3)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        ServicioFarmaceutico++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena4)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        SeguridadTrabajo++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena5)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        AcompañanteDomiciliario++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena6)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        CosmetologiaEstetica++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena7)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        ManicuristaPedicu++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena8)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        Peluqueria++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena9)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        MaquilladorArtisticoDeco++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena10)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        AuxiliarContable++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena11)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        AuxiliarAsisAdministrativo++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena12)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        Cocina++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena13)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        AtencionInfancia++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena14)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        UsoRaciMedica++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena15)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        AplicaProducNatu++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena16)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        vacunacion++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena17)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        HumaniServiSalud++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena18)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        SeguridadPaciente++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena19)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        VioleSexual++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena20)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        Inyectologia++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena21)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        TomaMueslabora++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena22)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        ConducAmbula++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena23)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        Camillero++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena24)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        SoporteVital++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena25)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        CuidadoNeonato++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena26)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        Radiologia++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena27)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        AuxiliosPrimeInfa++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena28)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        Hipertrofia++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena29)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        Lifting++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena30)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        DepilaCejas++;
    } else if (TxtPrograma.getText().equals(cadena31)) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        PestaPeloPelo++;
    }
    if (rbInscrito.isSelected()) {
        InscritosTotal++;
        InscritosDia++;
    } else if (rbMatriculado.isSelected()) {
        MatriculadosDia++;
        MatriculadosTotal++;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, MatriculadosTotal);
    }

    String strSentenciaInsert = String.format("INSERT INTO inscritos (ID,fecha,ciudad,programa,JorDiurna,JorNocturna,primerApell,segundoApell,nombres,fechaNaci,lugarNacimi,eps,ars,cualAseguradora,nivelSisben,otroSisben,docuCC,docuTi,docuOtro,NumDocume,Expedida,generoM,generoF,edad,tipoSangre,estadoCivilSoltero,estadoCivilCasada,estadoCivilUnionL,estadoCivilOtro,ocupacion,correoElec,direccionReside,telefono,barrio,estrato,entidadTrabaja,cargo,fechaIngresoEm,direccionEmpre,telefonoEmpre,nombreAcudiente,cedulaAcudiente,fechaNaciAcudiente,telefonoAcudiente,parentesco,profesionAcudiente,secundariaInstitu,secundariaCiudad,secundariaTitulo,secundariaAno,tecnicoInstitucion,tecnicoCiudad,tecnicoTitulo,tecnicoAno,univeInstitucion,univeCiudad,univeTitulo,univeAno,CulturaIndigena,culturaAfro,culturaReinser,culturaRoom,culturaCabezaF,culturaFrontera,culturaDezpla,pagoCredito,pagoContado) "
            + "VALUES (null, '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s', '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", oPersonas.getFecha(), oPersonas.getCiudad(), oPersonas.getPrograma(), oPersonas.getJorDiurna(), oPersonas.getJorNocturna(), oPersonas.getPrimerApell(), oPersonas.getSegundoApell(), oPersonas.getNombres(), oPersonas.getFechaNaci(), oPersonas.getLugarNacimi(), oPersonas.getEps(), oPersonas.getArs(), oPersonas.getCualAseguradora(), oPersonas.getNivelSisben(), oPersonas.getOtroSisben(), oPersonas.getDocuCC(), oPersonas.getDocuTi(), oPersonas.getDocuOtro(), oPersonas.getNumDocume(), oPersonas.getExpedida(), oPersonas.getGeneroM(), oPersonas.getGeneroF(), oPersonas.getEdad(), oPersonas.getTipoSangre(), oPersonas.getEstadoCivilSoltero(), oPersonas.getEstadiCivilCasada(), oPersonas.getEstadoCivilUnionL(), oPersonas.getEstadoCivilOtro(), oPersonas.getOcupacion(), oPersonas.getCorreoElec(), oPersonas.getDireccionReside(), oPersonas.getTelefono(), oPersonas.getBarrio(), oPersonas.getEstrato(), oPersonas.getEntidadTrabaja(), oPersonas.getCargo(), oPersonas.getFechaIngresoEm(), oPersonas.getDireccionEmpre(), oPersonas.getTelefonoEmpre(), oPersonas.getNombreAcudiente(), oPersonas.getCedulaAcudiente(), oPersonas.getFechaNaciAcudiente(), oPersonas.getTelefonoAcudiente(), oPersonas.getParentesco(), oPersonas.getProfesionAcudiente(), oPersonas.getSecundariaInstitu(), oPersonas.getSecundariaCiudad(), oPersonas.getSecundariaTitulo(), oPersonas.getSecundariaAno(), oPersonas.getTecnicoInstitucion(), oPersonas.getTecnicoCiudad(), oPersonas.getTecnicoTitulo(), oPersonas.getTecnicoAño(), oPersonas.getUniveInstitucion(), oPersonas.getUniveCiudad(), oPersonas.getUniveTitulo(), oPersonas.getUniveAno(), oPersonas.getCulturalIndigena(), oPersonas.getCulturaAfro(), oPersonas.getCulturaReinser(), oPersonas.getCulturaRoom(), oPersonas.getCulturaCabezaF(), oPersonas.getCulturaFrontera(), oPersonas.getCulturaDezpla(), oPersonas.getPagoCredito(), oPersonas.getPagoContado());

    objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInsert);
    this.mostrarDatos();
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Usuario Agregado");
}                                          
 private void btnEditarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    conexion objConexion = new conexion();
    personasBL oPersonas = recuperarDatosGui();
    String strSentenciaInsert = String.format("UPDATE inscritos SET fecha='%s',ciudad='%s',programa='%s',JorDiurna='%s',JorNocturna='%s',primerApell='%s',segundoApell='%s',nombres='%s',fechaNaci='%s',lugarNacimi='%s',eps='%s',ars='%s',cualAseguradora='%s',nivelSisben='%s',otroSisben='%s',docuCC='%s',docuTi='%s',docuOtro='%s',NumDocume='%s',Expedida='%s',generoM='%s',generoF='%s',edad='%s',tipoSangre='%s',estadoCivilSoltero='%s',estadoCivilCasada='%s',estadoCivilUnionL='%s',estadoCivilOtro='%s',ocupacion='%s',correoElec='%s',direccionReside='%s',telefono='%s',barrio='%s',estrato='%s',entidadTrabaja='%s',cargo='%s',fechaIngresoEm='%s',direccionEmpre='%s',telefonoEmpre='%s',nombreAcudiente='%s',cedulaAcudiente='%s',fechaNaciAcudiente='%s',telefonoAcudiente='%s',parentesco='%s',profesionAcudiente='%s',secundariaInstitu='%s',secundariaCiudad='%s',secundariaTitulo='%s',secundariaAno='%s',tecnicoInstitucion='%s',tecnicoCiudad='%s',tecnicoTitulo='%s',tecnicoAno='%s',univeInstitucion='%s',univeCiudad='%s',univeTitulo='%s',univeAno='%s',culturaIndigena='%s',culturaAfro='%s',CulturaReinser='%s',culturaRoom='%s',culturaCabezaDeF='%s',culturaFrontera='%s',culturaDezpla='%s',pagoCredito='%s',pagoContado='%s' WHERE ID=%d", oPersonas.getFecha(), oPersonas.getCiudad(), oPersonas.getPrograma(), oPersonas.getJorDiurna(), oPersonas.getJorNocturna(), oPersonas.getPrimerApell(), oPersonas.getSegundoApell(), oPersonas.getNombres(), oPersonas.getFechaNaci(), oPersonas.getLugarNacimi(), oPersonas.getEps(), oPersonas.getArs(), oPersonas.getCualAseguradora(), oPersonas.getNivelSisben(), oPersonas.getOtroSisben(), oPersonas.getDocuCC(), oPersonas.getDocuTi(), oPersonas.getDocuOtro(), oPersonas.getNumDocume(), oPersonas.getExpedida(), oPersonas.getGeneroM(), oPersonas.getGeneroF(), oPersonas.getEdad(), oPersonas.getTipoSangre(), oPersonas.getEstadoCivilSoltero(), oPersonas.getEstadiCivilCasada(), oPersonas.getEstadoCivilUnionL(), oPersonas.getEstadoCivilOtro(), oPersonas.getOcupacion(), oPersonas.getCorreoElec(), oPersonas.getDireccionReside(), oPersonas.getTelefono(), oPersonas.getBarrio(), oPersonas.getEstrato(), oPersonas.getEntidadTrabaja(), oPersonas.getCargo(), oPersonas.getFechaIngresoEm(), oPersonas.getDireccionEmpre(), oPersonas.getTelefonoEmpre(), oPersonas.getNombreAcudiente(), oPersonas.getCedulaAcudiente(), oPersonas.getFechaNaciAcudiente(), oPersonas.getTelefonoAcudiente(), oPersonas.getParentesco(), oPersonas.getProfesionAcudiente(), oPersonas.getSecundariaInstitu(), oPersonas.getSecundariaCiudad(), oPersonas.getSecundariaTitulo(), oPersonas.getSecundariaAno(), oPersonas.getTecnicoInstitucion(), oPersonas.getTecnicoCiudad(), oPersonas.getTecnicoTitulo(), oPersonas.getTecnicoAño(), oPersonas.getUniveInstitucion(), oPersonas.getUniveCiudad(), oPersonas.getUniveTitulo(), oPersonas.getUniveAno(), oPersonas.getCulturalIndigena(), oPersonas.getCulturaAfro(), oPersonas.getCulturaReinser(), oPersonas.getCulturaRoom(), oPersonas.getCulturaCabezaF(), oPersonas.getCulturaFrontera(), oPersonas.getCulturaDezpla(), oPersonas.getPagoCredito(), oPersonas.getPagoContado(), oPersonas.getID());

    objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInsert);
    this.mostrarDatos();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Usuario Editado");
}                                         

private void btnBorrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    conexion objConexion = new conexion();
    personasBL oPersonas = recuperarDatosGui();
    String strSentenciaInsert = String.format("DELETE FROM inscritos WHERE ID=%d", oPersonas.getID());

    objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInsert);
    this.mostrarDatos();
    this.limpiar();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Usuario Borrado");;
}                                         

public void mostrarDatos() {
    while (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
        model.removeRow(0);
    }
    conexion objConexion = new conexion();
    try {
        ResultSet resultado = objConexion.consultarRegistros("SELECT * FROM inscritos");
        while (resultado.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("ID"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("fecha"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("ciudad"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("programa"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("JorDiurna"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("JorNocturna"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("primerApell"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("segundoApell"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("nombres"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("fechaNaci"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("lugarNacimi"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("eps"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("ars"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("cualAseguradora"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("nivelSisben"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("otroSisben"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("docuCC"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("docuTi"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("docuOtro"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("NumDocume"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Expedida"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("generoM"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("generoF"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("edad"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("tipoSangre"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("estadoCivilSoltero"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("estadoCivilCasada"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("estadoCivilUnionL"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("estadoCivilOtro"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("ocupacion"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("correoElec"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("direccionreside"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("telefono"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("barrio"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("estrato"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("entidadTrabaja"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("cargo"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("fechaIngresoEm"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("direccionEmpre"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("telefonoEmpre"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("nombreAcudiente"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("cedulaAcudiente"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("fechaNaciAcudiente"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("telefonoAcudiente"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("parentesco"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("profesionAcudiente"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("secundariaInstitu"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("secundariaCiudad"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("secundariaTitulo"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("secundariaAno"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("tecnicoInstitucion"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("tecnicoCiudad"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("tecnicoTitulo"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("tecnicoAno"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("univeInstitucion"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("univeCiudad"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("univeTitulo"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("univeAno"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("culturaIndigena"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("culturaAfro"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("culturaReinser"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("culturaRoom"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("culturaCabezaF"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("culturaFrontera"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("culturaDezpla"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("pagoCredito"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("pagoContado"));

            Object[] oUsiario = {resultado.getString("ID"), resultado.getString("fecha"), resultado.getString("ciudad"), resultado.getString("programa"), resultado.getString("JorDiurna"), resultado.getString("JorNocturna"), resultado.getString("primerApell"), resultado.getString("segundoApell"), resultado.getString("nombres"), resultado.getString("fechaNaci"), resultado.getString("lugarNacimi"), resultado.getString("eps"),
                resultado.getString("ars"), resultado.getString("cualAseguradora"), resultado.getString("nivelSisben"), resultado.getString("otroSisben"), resultado.getString("docuCC"), resultado.getString("docuTi"),
                resultado.getString("docuOtro"), resultado.getString("NumDocume"), resultado.getString("Expedida"), resultado.getString("generoM"), resultado.getString("generoF"), resultado.getString("edad"),
                resultado.getString("tipoSangre"), resultado.getString("estadoCivilSoltero"), resultado.getString("estadoCivilCasada"), resultado.getString("estadoCivilUnionL"), resultado.getString("estadoCivilOtro"), resultado.getString("ocupacion"),
                resultado.getString("correoElec"), resultado.getString("direccionreside"), resultado.getString("telefono"), resultado.getString("barrio"), resultado.getString("estrato"), resultado.getString("entidadTrabaja"), resultado.getString("cargo"),
                resultado.getString("fechaIngresoEm"), resultado.getString("direccionEmpre"), resultado.getString("telefonoEmpre"), resultado.getString("nombreAcudiente"), resultado.getString("cedulaAcudiente"), resultado.getString("fechaNaciAcudiente"),
                resultado.getString("telefonoAcudiente"), resultado.getString("parentesco"), resultado.getString("profesionAcudiente"), resultado.getString("secundariaInstitu"), resultado.getString("secundariaCiudad"), resultado.getString("secundariaTitulo"),
                resultado.getString("secundariaAno"), resultado.getString("tecnicoInstitucion"), resultado.getString("tecnicoCiudad"), resultado.getString("tecnicoTitulo"), resultado.getString("tecnicoAno"), resultado.getString("univeInstitucion"),
                resultado.getString("univeCiudad"), resultado.getString("univeTitulo"), resultado.getString("univeAno"), resultado.getString("culturaIndigena"), resultado.getString("culturaAfro"), resultado.getString("culturaReinser"),
                resultado.getString("culturaRoom"), resultado.getString("culturaCabezaF"), resultado.getString("culturaFrontera"), resultado.getString("culturaDezpla"), resultado.getString("pagoCredito"), resultado.getString("pagoContado")};
            model.addRow(oUsiario);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: La mejor forma de explicarnos esto es mostrando COMO TEXTO el código que genera este formulario

Comment: yo inicio el programa, y voy a escribir en esos textfield y no deja como si estuvieran bloqueados, pero tienen la opción editable activa

Comment: Sin ver el código es improbable que recibas una respuesta. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Qué hace `mostrarDatos`?

Comment: me trae los datos a la tabla